# Fade blur element

Tags: wpf, animation, fade

So i have `WPF` application and at some point when my application doing its stuff i want to `blur` my grid with all my controllers for specific time and then back so currently i am using this method:

```
private void BlurElement(Grid grid, double value)
{
    Grid g = grid;
    BlurBitmapEffect blurEffect = new BlurBitmapEffect();
    blurEffect.Radius = value;
    g.BitmapEffect = blurEffect;
}
```

**Usage**

```
BlurElement(myGrid, 30);
```

And back: `BlurElement(myGrid, 0);`

So this works fine but now i want this blur to occur with fade element so i create this timer:

```
private DispatcherTimer fadeTimer;

fadeTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
fadeTimer.Tick += FadeTimer_Tick;
fadeTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 100);
```

And from my `Timer` tick:

```
private void FadeTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BlurElement(myGrid, count += 1);
    if (counter == 30)
        fadeTimer.Stop();
}
```

Then it is done gradually.

So my question is that if there is more simple way to achieve that without this `Timer` or maybe some library (i am using `Windows7` mostly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides that it is inefficient to create a new BlurBitmapEffect on each timer tick, WPF BitmapEffects are animatable. So you could simply declare the effect in XAML

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.BitmapEffect>
        <BlurBitmapEffect x:Name="blurBitmapEffect" Radius="0"/>
    </Grid.BitmapEffect>
    ...
</Grid>
```

and start an animation somewhere in code behind:

```
blurBitmapEffect.BeginAnimation(
    BlurBitmapEffect.RadiusProperty,
    new DoubleAnimation(30, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)));
```

---

Or just do all in XAML, e.g. like this:

```
<Grid.BitmapEffect>
    <BlurBitmapEffect Radius="0"/>
</Grid.BitmapEffect>
<Grid.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="BitmapEffect.Radius"
                    To="30" Duration="0:0:3"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
</Grid.Triggers>
```

Comment: and if i want to return it back just replace the 20 with the 0 ?

Comment: Give it a try. Animation can also be run with AutoReverse set. Take a look at the online documentation of DoubleAnimation.

Comment: And if i have several Grid i need to add for each one this Grid.BitmapEffect ?

Comment: Come on. Try something. It should be possible to create a single BlurBitmapEffect once and assign it to the BitmapEffect property of several Grids. Then animate that single BlurBitmapEffect instance.